# cannot predict from rpart

Tags: r, predict, rpart

I have a matrix of features (in columns) where the last column is a class label. Observations are in rows.

I use `rpart` in R to build a decision tree over a subset of my data and test it with predict using the rest of the data. The code to learn the tree is

```
fTree <- rpart(feature$a ~ feature$m, data = feature[fold != k, ],
  method = "class", parms = list(split = "gini"))
```

The code to test it is

```
predFeature <- predict(fTree, newdata = feature[fold == k, ],
  type = "class")
```

where `k` is an integer that I use to select a subset of the data, while `fold` is a matrix I use to create different subsets.

I get a warning message that I know some of you know already:

```
'newdata' had 306 rows but variables found have 3063 rows.
```

I read a post related to this but I failed in understanding the reason.
So, further help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say for sure because your example is not reproducible but I am rather certain that the problem is the following: You have fitted your tree with

```
rpart(feature$a ~ feature$m, data = feature[fold != k, ], ...)
```

Thus, the dependent variable is always `feature$a` from the *full* `feature` data set (which apparently has 3063 observation) and *not* from the subset `feature[fold != k, ]`. This works without error but is not the tree you wanted to fit. Consequently, the prediction is surprised because the `newdata` just has 306 observations but then these are not used but *still* the *full* data set due to the hard-coded `feature$a` in the formula.

Using

```
rpart(a ~ m, data = feature[fold != k, ], ...)
```

is easier to read, less to type, and should fix the problems you observe.

Comment: So, when a say a ~ m, I'm saying which var is dependent and which is indep. In this case the data used to fit the tree is feature[fold != k, ]. Likewise predict uses the data in newdata. So rpart and predict use different data sets. However when I use feature$a ~ feature$m, apart from the type of the variable (dep. vs indep.) I am also stating what data shall be used in fitting the tree. This also implies that predict must use the same data set. This is what I understand from your words. I must say that this is a bit weird, the reason why I was stuck at first. You're right and helpful. Nice!

Comment: Yes. The point about formulas in R (statements with ~) is that you conveniently separate the variable description for a model from the actual data used. But by accessing a variable from a specific data set with the $ operator, you overrule that behavior.